# Winform: Binding a custom control property to a BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, bindinglist

I'm trying to create a binding from my custom control to objects that are in a BindingList.

While with textbox, I can easily write

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text",myBindingList,"PropertyOfObjectOfBindingList")
```

With my custom property "Value", this thing doesn't work (the object doesn't get updated).

What should I implement with my custom control to make it works? I already implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, but it doesn't work.

I just want make this line works:

```
customControl.DataBindings.Add("CustomProperty",myBindingList,"PropertyOfObjectOfBindingList")
```

**EDIT 1:**

I read this around web: http://kbalertz.com/327413/control-using-Visual.aspx however is not working for me at the moment, maybe I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said your bound object doesn't get updated (I assume from Control -> Object changes), but it is bound correctly, maybe this will help:

```
customControl.DataBindings.Add("CustomProperty", list, "BoundObjectProperty", 
    false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: I'm having another problem now, what if I want to use a CUSTOM collection as datasource in this case? I created a custom collection but events are not fired. Any suggestion? Watch this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105102/create-a-custom-collection-like-bindinglist-that-works-with-listbox-to-create-a-l

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by myself:

While the article I linked is a good suggestion, there is a wrong part; you don't have to create an event in your custom class with PropertyChangedEventHandler, but just with EventHandler.

```
public event EventHandler CustomPropertyChanged;
```

Is enough to make everything works. Obviusly you have to call it when your property changes

**EDIT 1:**

I discovered a bad thing, while on textboxes, if the control lose focus the bindinglist get updated, on my custom controls this thing happens only when I change selected item in listbox.

I don't find a way to solve this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Implementing complex data binding in custom controls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataBindCustomControls.aspx) article will help.

Comment: I'm not sure it fits my problem, I read it but I don't see any DataBindings.Add anywhere, only changing datasource and things like that, but as I've said I'm already using a BindingList as datasource and it works well. My problem is about the control