# Create a custom collection like BindingList that works with ListBox to create a ListChanging event

Tags: c#, data-binding, listbox, bindinglist

I have a situation where I need to know when an item is **going** to be added/removed/modified in the collection.

I tried by inheriting BindingList in a class that will trigger these events, however the "adding" event doesn't work. The only way I found it working is by overriding EndNew() method, however I don't find a way to get which object is going to be added in this method *(if someone has a solution for this, it's ok too!)*.

So built a totally new class which inherits from same interfaces/class of BindingList and implemented everything (I didn't inherit, however, ICancelAddNew).

I bound it through databindings to my listbox and I find out that nothing works (listchanged events neither listchanging events). How can I simulate BindingList behavior on a listbox?

Any suggestion heavily appreciated, I don't have any other ideas for a workaround

**EDIT 1:**

This is my collection: http://pastie.org/1978601
And this is how I bind the collection to the ListBox

```
        SpellCasterManager.CurrentProfile.ButtonsMacro.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(ButtonsMacro_ListChanged);
        SpellCasterManager.CurrentProfile.ButtonsMacro.ListChanging += new Expand.ComponentModel.ListChangingEventHandler(ButtonsMacro_ListChanging);
gumpButton.DataBindings.Add("Value", SpellCasterManager.CurrentProfile.ButtonsMacro, "GumpIndex", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Actually under subscribed events there is just a MessageBox.Show("bla");

Comment: Maybe you should post something more about "why" you want to know when an item is going to be added/removed/modified? Because if you want to block certain UI actions before that, then you can setup some sort of event or binding to disable add/remove/modify operations while some activity is under processing.

Comment: What I would like to do is to store in a List the "previous value" of each property changed to a BindingList item, because I would like to use it for something similar to Ctrl + Z

Comment: So in clear words, you want Undo/Redo functionality for your application? Then you might have to change many things because each change within property and collection will need to be store as unit of work that can be applied or removed. There are some codeplex project that provide some framework to implement Undo/Redo.

Comment: Well, I won't use the Memento approach but I would like to use the Command approach, that's why I prefer to detect changing and not changed events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your collection won't detect property changes in an existing item because it doesn't hook into the item's property changed events as it is added to the collection.
- `BindingList<T>` does listen to PropertyChanged on your item and does fire a ListChanged event when an item is added to the BindingList and it does include the index at which is is added. Try it in a test app without WinForms.
- Adding an existing item is not the same as AddNew(). The AddingNew event is only called when AddNew() is called and allows you to supply the new instance.
- When WinForms is involved, things get more complicated. There is the CurrencyManager to think about and also BindingSource. If no events are firing at all then check to see if you are using the CurrencyManager/BindingSource you think you are.
- I don't think anything in the framework uses INotifyPropertyChanging, only the original INotifyPropertyChanged. You might want to use Reflector on BindingList to see how the hooking is done and then try to incorporate INotifyPropertyChanging if your item supports it.

Comment: Ok while your answer talks about a lot of things, the important thing is the first one: My collection didn't hook events. However, I thought CollectionBase would have handled that for me; I were wrong obviusly. Now it's working in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow MSDN guidelines? Your collection class should extend `CollectionBase` and implement `IBindingList` - and that should be fine.

Also, you might want your collection *item* to implement `IEditableObject` in order to support `*Edit` operations. This however is not required - more importantly, your collection item should have a way to notify parent collection when it changes (either by following code provided on MSDN, or using for example [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)).

---

You can find working binding sample implementing custom `CustomersList` on [`IBindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx) doc page (`Customer` class can be found on [`IEditableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) doc page).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm testing. I'll give you news about this, thanks again.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: can you post some code, esp. `Add` method from your collection and how you bind to control..?

Answer (score 2):

After getting clear idea of what you are looking for i will suggest following things

Here is a great undo framework which provides lot of functionality. 
http://undo.codeplex.com/

Here is sample,
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/07/02/samples-for-the-undo-framework.aspx

And in your case, instead of trying to hook on adding/editing events, it's better to track after added/modified/deleted event if you store their initial state. So if the item was removed, in your previous state you will have the item already if you started tracking from the start state of your program.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, I prefer a Command pattern approach instead of a memento approach, that's why I needed tracking changing events and I managed to make it works.